# It is possible to skip generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

can I skip one generic type in a function?

```
public Task<T2> Example<T2,T>() {
  ...
}
```

can I use

```
await Example<int>();
```

Instead of

```
await Example<int, int>();
```

but without making a second function.
I tryed to define the T2 value as `null`but I cant use `NULL`

```
await Example<int, null>();
```

**Edit**
the result is not the problem. I edited the code above. T2 is the result and will never be `null`.

Comment: Short answer - no. The longer answer will depend on you explaining _why_ you think you need this.

Comment: `null` is not a type. You can't pass it to something expecting a type and expect it to work.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Its fine. I dont need help for the result. I want just know if its possible lol.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `await Example<int, int>();` because of the way you declared the function's type here:

`public Task<T2> Example<T,T2>() {   ... }`